# Using jQuery to select all the punctuation marks in the paragraphs and assign a class to them?

Tags: jquery

I want to change the colors to the punctuation marks (and other symbols) in paragraphs. I have something like this:

```
"Hello I'm a web & graphic designer."
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
"Hello I<strong class="highlighted">'</strong>m a web
<strong class="highlighted">&</strong> graphic designer
<strong class="highlighted">.</strong>"
```

Any suggestions to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue on some of my project and got it straight by using [jQuery replaceText plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/)

In your case you can use the plugin like this:

```
$("body *").replaceText( /([,!@#$%^&*()\u9999])/gi, "<strong class='highlighted'>$1</strong>" );
```

*This will work on your entire page.*

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with regex replacement:

```
txt = $('#the-paragraph').text();
txt = txt.replace(/(['&.e])/g,"<span class=\"highlighted\">$1</span>");
$('#the-paragraph').html(txt);
```

See the example in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/KcyEs/1/

Comment: Just make sure you don't type a `^` as the first character in the character class. ;)

Comment: Thanks! How can I change that so that it applies to the whole page?

Comment: You'd have to run it for each paragraph you want to format. For instance, you could use a selector like `p` or `p.formatMe`, or you could define a function that takes any jQuery object as a parameter and performs the replacement on it. My code snippet uses `.text()` to extract the text you want to format, meaning any nested HTML is lost in the process, so make sure you don't have nested elements within the paragraph. If you were to use `.html()` instead the nested HTML would not be destroyed but it would also be subject to replacement, which could break it.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the content you want to change has a `class` of `"highlighted"` you can do something like this:

**JavaScript**

```
$(".highlighted").addClass("coloured-text");
```

**CSS**

```
.coloured-text {
    color: red;
}
```

If you need to add the classes by hand have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/bUrNj/) that I've knocked up. This uses a regular expression to wrap pre-defined punctuation with a `<span>` which has the `highlighted` class.

Comment: Or only CSS : `.highlighted{ color: red; }`

Comment: I think it doesn't have any class from the beginning - the code snippet is the result he wants.

Comment: Code updated to cater for inserting the `highlighted` `span`s.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's no other html in your paragraph:

```
$("#paragraph").html(function (i, text) {
    return text.replace(/([&\.'])/g, "<strong class='highlighted'>$1</strong>");
});
```

Comment: That single quote in the regex looks like it belongs inside the character class, correct?

Comment: One more thing: what would happen if you want to replace any of `<>="`? Wouldn't they be replaced in any nested HTML code as well?